# Oracle connect by with aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

As an example I have query with CONNECT BY statement:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, LEVEL
   FROM employees
   CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```

This query produces following result:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 MANAGER_ID    SALES     LEVEL
----------- ------------------------- ---------- -------- ----------
        101 Kochhar                          100     121          1
        108 Greenberg                        101      80          2
        109 Faviet                           108      54          3
        110 Chen                             108      23          3
```

I am looking for a way to compute the share of employees sales in manager+employees sales, i.e 80/(121 + 80), (54 + 23)/(54 + 23 + 80).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives desired values, but I'm not sure if I didn't overcomplicate things:

```
select employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, suma, prior suma psuma,
    cast(suma / (prior suma + suma) as number(8, 4)) sumb
  from (
    with t as (SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, LEVEL lvl
       FROM employees
       where employee_id in (101, 108, 109, 110)
       CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
       start with employee_id = 101)
    select employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, lvl,
      sum(sales) over (partition by manager_id) suma from t) t
  connect by prior employee_id = manager_id
  start with employee_id=101
  order siblings by employee_id
```

Results:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME      MANAGER_ID      SALES       SUMA      PSUMA       SUMB
----------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        101 Kochhar               100        121        121                       
        108 Greenberg             101         80         80        121       ,398 
        109 Faviet                108         54         77         80      ,4904 
        110 Chen                  108         23         77         80      ,4904
```

---

**Edit:** 
The same query as above, but little more readable, the steps are more visible, I hope.

T1 is basically your query, just filtered interesting rows from [HR schema](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#COMSC001).

T2 is query with aggregated sums for same managers (this one groups Faviet and Chen).

Last query is again hierarchical, but seeks for allready aggregated sums.

```
with t1 as (
  SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, LEVEL lvl
    FROM employees where employee_id in (101, 108, 109, 110)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
    start with employee_id = 101),
t2 as (select employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, lvl,
    sum(sales) over (partition by manager_id) suma from t1)
select employee_id, last_name, manager_id, sales, suma dividend, 
    prior suma + suma divider, 
    cast(suma / (prior suma + suma) as number(8, 4)) result
  from t2 connect by prior employee_id = manager_id
  start with employee_id=101
  order siblings by employee_id


EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME        MANAGER_ID      SALES   DIVIDEND    DIVIDER     RESULT
----------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        101 Kochhar                 100        121        121                       
        108 Greenberg               101         80         80        201       ,398 
        109 Faviet                  108         54         77        157      ,4904 
        110 Chen                    108         23         77        157      ,4904
```